# php / mysql to query one table with multiple identical fields and create one unique entry for each field in a second table

Tags: php, mysql

A bit difficult to explain this one.  I have a table of transactions which contains multiple entries of names.  I want to scan this table and create a unique entry for each name in a second table.  For instance table 1 contains :-

john smith
pete jones 
sue james
john smith
john smith
pete jones 
sue james
john smith

after the query I want table 2 to contain:-

john smith
pete jones
sue james

thanks for any advice

Comment: If you just require a unique set of names wouldn't doing distinct simply work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to use `DISTINCT` keyword in sql. It selects distinct values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name from table_1
```

And you will retrieve unique names. And all you have to do is to loop through in the search result and do an `INSERT` statement to insert to your new table.

Comment: Actually thinking about it more I did not explain well - basically I want to total all the sales for each name not just get a uniqhe list.  So I echo 1 line for say john that has a total of all his sales - any ideas - thanks so much and sorry for not being clear in the first place :-)